# If my website rank for bad words (like piracy) on Google can it effect SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords

My website is a legal site, but since I have a message published on some articles with sentences like "we don't publish pirate tools...", my website now ranks for piracy keywords ("something crack" etc).

Should I worry about it as Google may tag my website as a bad site and drop my rankings?

Answer (score 2):

With that logic you could have children's stories and many innocent sites being flagged as "bad". No, it doesn't work like that. Context is everything.

But, from the other standpoint... just because a site's subject matter is in that "bad" realm isn't necessarily a reason to reduce it's ranking (with some obvious exceptions).

*Aside:*

> "we don't publish pirate tools..." / "something crack"

Is this a translation? I'm struggling to think of a context in which you would actually write that (it doesn't really make sense)?

Comment: I just gave an example, and sorry for my English.